# hard code image size in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am retrieving images from the web on my site. Users upload images to the site. I want these images displayed evenly across the screen, like you would see on eventbrite, in a table form. But now, my code reads the size of the image uploaded, and changes the size of the container depending on the image, and it results in bad looking layouts, like this:

[image]

How can I make it so that each image is hard coded to be 360x220?

Here is my current code:

```
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
         <div class="thumbnail">
           //image goes here
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I tried looking in bootstrap.css file, and changed it to this:

```
        .img-thumbnail {
           display: inline-block;
           width: 360;
           max-width: 100%;
           height: 220;
           padding: 4px;
           line-height: 1.42857143;
           background-color: #fff;
           border: 1px solid #ddd;
           border-radius: 4px;
        -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
        transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
```

}

but that did not work either.

Answer (score 0):

you have not put px in width and height in correct format as change it

```
.img-thumbnail 
{
width: 360px;
height: 220px;
}
```

may help you